# Exclude certain tokens from Elasticsearch's lowercase filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like all words to be indexed as lowercased tokens, except for a select few. I thought I could accomplish this using the `condition` token filter in combination with the `lowercase` filter:

Base off my reading of this page in the docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-condition-tokenfilter.html

I added this filter, to exempt the word "WHO":

```
{
   "filter":{
      "smart_lowercase_filter":{
         "filter":[
            "lowercase"
         ],
         "type":"condition",
         "script":{
            "source":"token.term != 'WHO'"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However, "WHO" still gets tokenized as "who". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `CharSequence.toString()` method, otherwise you compare a `CharSequence` with a `String` and that doesn't work.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "smart_lowercase_filter": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "condition",
          "script": {
            "source": "token.term.toString() != 'WHO'"
                                     ^
                                     |
                                  add this
          }
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "smart_lowercase_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you'll get this:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "hey",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "WHO",                  <------------
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "are",
      "start_offset" : 8,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "you",
      "start_offset" : 12,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```